# How to update googleMap marker at regular interval?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to update the marker position in a googleMap at regular interval of 5 seconds. I am getting different Lattitude and Longitude value from server which I need to show in the googleMap with a marker. I tried the following,

```
void updateCabLocation(final LatLng location) {

    if(myMarker == null) {
        myMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).
                icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.myMarkerImage)));
    }else {
        myMarker.setPosition(location);
    }
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 15);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

}

Runnable updateMarker = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                    updateCabLocation(location); // location value changes each time. I have deleted that piece of code here.
                    handler.postDelayed(updateMarker, 5000);
        }
    };
```

I am calling `updateCabLocation` method at a regular interval of 5 seconds.It updates nicely but shows `ANR` message. Is there any other way to achieve it ?

Comment: Just a note: why do you have two camera updates? You only need one of them. @MD There is no reason to remove the marker when updating its location.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes you're right.

Comment: Where are you calling `updateCabLocation`? Are you using an `AsyncTask`? Could you post that code?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: I was doing some R&D and its still there. I will remove one. Thanks for marking it.

Comment: Otherwise I don't see anything wrong with this, especially if it's called every 5 seconds. Is it for sure the interaction with Google Maps that's causing it? If you comment this out does the ANR disappear?

Comment: @antonio: I have updated the code. Have a look.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: No it doesn't . I mean yeah, if I remove map interaction code then there is nothing in that method so no ANR.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to do it-

1. You clear the map every time and then draw a new marker every time.
2. Animate the same marker to different location every time you get a new location in your location updates.

Comment: Well, if you see my code, I am not creating a `Marker` each time. If it's null then only I am creating it.

Comment: thats a good trick. just update the location . but if you want some crisp and nice movement on your movement you should go for animating the marker.